# How to enable batch upload with django 2.x (or 3)?

Tags: django

I have this model that accepts files, calculates the md5 sum and if that value is not yet in the database the file is stored. It works for one file at a time.

```
# models.py
class RawFile(models.Model):
    # use the custom storage class fo the FileField
    orig_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=media_file_name, storage=file_system_storage)
    md5sum = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=timezone.now, unique=True)
    created = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Saving new raw file.', self.md5sum)
        if not self.pk:  # file is new
            md5 = hashlib.md5()
            for chunk in self.orig_file.chunks():
                md5.update(chunk)
            self.md5sum = md5.hexdigest()
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        print('Saving new raw file.', self.md5sum)
        super(RawFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

    def __str__(self):
        return basename(self.orig_file.name)

    @property
    def abs_path(self): 
        return f'{MEDIA_ROOT}/{self.orig_file}'

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return basename(self.abs_path)

    @property
    def rawtools_status(self):
        path = dirname(self.abs_path)
        if isfile('QcDataTable.csv'):
            return 'Done'
        elif isfile(join(path, 'rawtools.txt')):
            return 'Running'
        return 'New file'

    @property    
    def href(self):
        return os.path.dirname('/'+self.orig_file.name)

    def link(self):
        print(self.href)
        return mark_safe(r'<a href="{}">Output</a>'.format(self.href))

    link.short_description = 'Browse'


# pipelines/forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import RawFile
```

I changed the upload form so that multiple files can be uploaded at the same time, though here only the last file in the batch gets stored.

```
# forms.py
class UploadRawForm(forms.ModelForm):
    orig_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = RawFile
        fields = ['orig_file']

    error_css_class = 'error'
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

How can I archive a multi-file upload, so that on the backend, each file is treated separately?

UPDATE: With this code the multiple file upload seems to work.

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views import generic
from .forms import UploadRawForm
from .models import RawFile

def upload_raw_view(request):
    '''Upload RAW files. Working for single file uploads'''
    form = UploadRawForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadRawForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if not form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'pipelines/upload.html', context={'form': form})
        if form.is_valid():
            files = request.FILES.getlist('orig_file')
            for f in files:
                rawfile = RawFile(orig_file = f)
                rawfile.save()
            return render(request, 'pipelines/upload.html', {'form': form})
    return render(request, 'pipelines/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted how you handle the form in your view, but I think you need to use "getlist" for fields containing multiple values, like so

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('orig_file')
if form.is_valid():
   for f in files:
       rawfile = RawFile(orig_file = f)
       rawfile.save()
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files) for details

Comment: I added the content of views.py. I just save the form.

Comment: I don't think your simple approach will work in case of multiple files. You need to iterate over the files and save each one individually as stated in the docs

Comment: When I look at data in upload_raw_view it only contains one file already, even after selecting and uploading multiple files.

Comment: In this example `f` is just the filename, not the file itself. If I could iterate over the files and submit a single file at a time?

Comment: Well no, it is not just the name, it is an InMemoryUploadedFile. However, you are right, my original approach would not work. I updated the answer

Comment: It seems to work!! Thank you so much. I am going to upload my example accordingly.